# Simple round function doesn't round

Tags: php, rounding

I'm trying to round one value to 8 symbol after decimal but it doesn't round anything. For example:

```
12/653.44
result: 0.018364348677767
```

I want to round and output 8 symbols only after `,`.
This is the function:

```
public static function getUSDRate()
{
  $urldata = get_curl_content('https://example.com/');
  $rates = json_decode($urldata, TRUE);
  if (!$rates) {
        return '-';
  }
  $usdRate = $rates['USD']['sell'];
    if (!$usdRate) {
        return '-';
    }
    return round($usdRate, 8);
}
```

Function calling: `$singles->price/getUSDRate()`
Then when I call the function it echoes whole number...

Comment: Seems to work fine here: https://3v4l.org/HDCf9

Comment: It works perfectly: `0.01836435` for me of course. The error will be somewhere else.

Comment: That's really strange. Why I've got full number on the page

Comment: Show the function call...

Comment: Have you used the function appropriately? Please show the full code where you're calling the function and passing the value.

Comment: I have updated my question. `$singles->price` coming from database.

Comment: But where are you echoing it??? The code shows no attempt to print anything...

Comment: here `$singles->price/getUSDRate()`. This is in loop

Comment: echo round(12/653.44,8); 

this prints 0.01836435

Comment: But why I must use `round` on the echo? Can't I use it like I'm tried on the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the result to have only 8 decimals, you should use:

```
echo round($singles->price/getUSDRate(), 8);
```

With the information in your question, we can see that you are rounding too early, since you perform more calculations later. You could probably remove the rounding from `getUSDRate()` function.

If you want to get 8 decimals in the number you display, the rounding must be performed after all the computations. You could modify the `getUSDRate()` function to include the rounding there:

```
public static function getUSDRate($value)
{
  $urldata = get_curl_content('https://example.com/');
  $rates = json_decode($urldata, TRUE);
  if (!$rates) {
        return '-';
  }
  $usdRate = $rates['USD']['sell'];
    if (!$usdRate) {
        return '-';
    }
    return round($value/$usdRate, 8);
}

echo getUSDRate($singles->price);
```

Note: the declaration of `getUSDRate` function indicates it is part of a class. In that case the call to this static function should be:

```
echo YOUR_CLASS_HERE::getUSDRate($singles->price);
```

Comment: It'd be important to mention that the rounding from inside the function isn't needed using this. Specially if this answer meant to make the function more 'flexible' by returning the original value ;)

Comment: Thank's for the answer. Ideally I want to use round inside function but i guess will use this for now..

Comment: @Garg I included a modified version of your function with the rounding at the end.